# Permission Issues When Removing Directory

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, privileges

I am using Windows 8.1, and am trying to remove a directory (specifically a Cygwin install directory). I keep getting this error:

> You need permission to perform this action.
>
> You require permission from MY_MACHINE\michael to make changes to this folder.

I **am** logged in as `MY_MACHINE\michael` so why am I getting this error?

I tried running `del cygwin` in the command prompt with administrative privilidges, but the directory is still there. How can I delete this directory?

Comment: I know nothing about Cygwin, but as far as the permission issue try using runas. `runas /profile /user:michael "C:\cmd.exe"` Then in the new prompt try running your remove folder command.

Comment: Try using `rmdir /S /Q "C:\foldertodelete"`. del is for files, rmdir is for directories and their files.

Comment: this can happen when a handle is still open to this folder. Search for open handles to this folder with ProcessExplorer.